# create new core directories in SOLR on the fly

Tags: lucene, solr, distributed, solrj

i am using solr 1.4.1 for building a distributed search engine, but i dont want to use only one index file - i want to create new core "index"-directories on the fly in my java code.

i found following rest api to create new cores using an **EXISTING** core directory (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin).

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=coreX&instanceDir=path_to_instance_directory&config=config_file_name.xml&schema=schem_file_name.xml&dataDir=data
```

is there a way to create a new core without an extisting core directory? has solr such a function? via rest or in the solrj-api? thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not currently possible to programmatically submit your schema and config to Solr to create a new core. [Here's the JIRA issue about it](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-791).

As mentioned in the comments, you can work around it by using something like WebDAV or scp or sftp.